# How to use Prop from UTT in Agda

Tags: lo.logic, dependent-type, agda

In Ulf Norell's thesis he mentions that Agda is based on Luo's UTT. However, I can't find a way to use Prop there. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Agda this is done by tagging types as "irrelevant". It's a kind of quotenting. A function from an irrelevant to a (relevant) type must be constant (and Agda enforces this). You can read more about it on the [Agda wiki Irrelevance page](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=ReferenceManual.Irrelevance).

Answer (score 5):

Andrej answer covers uses of extraction, but as far as *expressiveness* goes, I believe that having impredicative Prop leads to a system that is strictly stronger than Agda. In fact "Martin-Löf type theory with universes" is sometimes called "Luo's predicative UTT"

One subtle issue is **induction-recursion**, which gives Agda significant power and seems to be absent in Coq. However there is a [trick](http://www.cs.ru.nl/~venanzio/publications/induction_recursion.ps) by V. Capretta (It's likely been independently discovered) which allows expressing such definitions in Coq.

Comment: Agda's irrelevance is about judgemental equality, so talking about extraction is a misrepresentation (more directly covered by [erasure/runtime irrelevance](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.1.3/language/runtime-irrelevance.html#runtime-irrelevance), even though irrelevance should entail erasability). Irrelevance should give some gain in expressiveness, but not as much as impredicativity would.

Answer (score 2):

Now Agda supports `Prop`: https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.1.3/language/prop.html

However, Agda's `Prop` is *predicative* and *definitionally irrelevant*, so it's still not as strong as discussed in Cody's answer.

To use it, one needs to supply `--prop` to Agda. This can be done by adding `{-# OPTIONS --prop #-}` at the top of an Agda file.